Automated Data(text) extraction from url at specific time daily and auto add to table and display on wordpress website
Hi What is a free way for our wordpress website to automatically daily save/record the Interest rate value indicated with a % sign at UTC 11:00 from https://www.binance.com/en/earn/simple-earn?asset=USDT&productId=USDT001 into a table in a page of our website?
Tried following chatgpt ideas but they were too complex to execute
